# Endfloat compilation error

Tags: endfloat

Why is the following MWE giving me an error? I want use endfloat to number the tables in each chapter with I, II, III etc.  I also want to print a list of tables and figures at the end of each chapter rather than the end of the document.

Also, I can't get the table that is on a landscape page in the document to display as landscape on it's own page in the list of tables at the end. The table is very wide, so I need to keep it on a landscape page on its own.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage[]{endfloat}
\renewcommand{\theposttable}{\Roman{theposttbl}}
\renewcommand{\thepostfigure}{\Roman{postfig}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\Roman{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Roman{table}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{This is Chapter 1}
Some text in chapter 1.  See my figure \ref{tab:table1}.

\begin{table}
\caption{First Table} \label{tab:table1}
\end{table}

\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\chapter{This is Chapter 2}
Some text in chapter 2.  See my figure \ref{tab:table2}.

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\caption{First Table} \label{tab:table2}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use `landscape` in this way, because `endfloat` wouldn't be able to catch it. However, the `endfloat` package knows how to manage new environments.

Note that you had an error in the redefinition of `\theposttable`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{endfloat}

\renewcommand{\theposttable}{\Roman{posttbl}}
\renewcommand{\thepostfigure}{\Roman{postfig}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\Roman{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Roman{table}}

% new environment for landscape tables    
\newenvironment{ltable}
  {\begin{landscape}\begin{table}}
  {\end{table}\end{landscape}}

% make it known to endfloat
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{ltable}{table}

\begin{document}

\chapter{This is Chapter 1}
Some text in chapter 1.  See my figure \ref{tab:table1}.

\begin{table}
\caption{First Table} \label{tab:table1}
\end{table}

\chapter{This is Chapter 2}
Some text in chapter 2.  See my figure \ref{tab:table2}.

\begin{ltable}
\caption{First Table} \label{tab:table2}
\end{ltable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I put a list of tables after each chapter, rather than just once at the end of the document?

Comment: @user2146441 That's a completely different question.

Comment: I had the following environment set up for landscape pages. How can I add this to your example above? \fancypagestyle{myplain}
{
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
  \renewcommand\footrulewidth{0pt}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
}

Comment: @user2146441 Add `\thispagestyle{myplain}` after `\begin{landscape}`